# Sum columns in python

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a text file. It should match with string in column1 and add with colum2,3,4 and prints it in a different file. So, far my code is:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/ankr/Desktop/samp.txt', sep=",", header=None)
data.columns = ['name','val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5']
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
summary = my_df.groupby('name').sum()
print summary
```

**Example Input:**

```
abc,1,1,1,1,0

def,1,0,0,0,1

abc,1,0,0,0,1

def,0,0,0,0,1

xyz,1,1,1,1,0
```

**Expected output**

```
abc,2,1,1,1,1

def,1,1,1,1,2

xyz,1,1,1,1,0
```

**Samp.txt** file

```
abc,1,1,1,1,0
abc,1,1,1,1,0
Def,1,0,0,0,1
Def,1,0,0,0,1
```

**My output:**

```
  name        val1    val2  val3      val4    val5
0  abc         1       1     1         1       0
1  abc         1       1     1         1       0
2  Def         1       0     0         0       1
3  Def         1       0     0         0       1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried. I have updated

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('abc',1,1,1,1,0),
        ('def',1,0,0,0,1),
        ('abc',1,0,0,0,1),
        ('def',0,0,0,0,1),
        ('xyz',1,1,1,1,0)]

my_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Sumarize by first column then sum the other columns`
summary = my_df.groupby([0]).sum()
#This line will create a cvs file named 'my_output.csv'
summary.to_csv('my_output.csv', index=True, header=False)

output at file:
abc,2,1,1,1,1
def,1,0,0,0,2
xyz,1,1,1,1,0
```

Comment: I just added the file creation. it looks like the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that your 6 columns are ['name', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] and your dataframe is called df

```
df.groupby('name').sum()
```

This will sum all your a, b, c, d, e columns grouped by the first column 'name'